# QML DatePicker Object Update when date is Clicked

Tags: qt, datepicker, qml

trying to create a page which updates dates automatically when a new date selected.

First i created a datepicker qml. Which gives me the date,month,year. When i clicked a date and use the following snippet, it prints the date. I want to update the row in Test.qml when an date clicked on DatePicker object. ***Code is working but with an error.*** I couldn't understand what should i write instead of

```
onClicked: selectDate(date)
```

it updates everything but throws an error also on the console which is

**`qt.qml.context: qrc:/project/Test.qml:53:9 Parameter "date" is not declared. Injection of parameters into signal handlers is deprecated. Use JavaScript functions with formal parameters instead.`**

**Code snippet i used in Test.qml:**

```
DatePicker {
    Component.onCompleted: set(new Date()) // today
    onClicked:             print('onClicked', Qt.formatDate(date, 'M/d/yyyy'))
}
```

**DatePicker.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.0

ListView {
    id: root

 // public
    function set(date) { // new Date(2019, 10 - 1, 4)
        selectedDate = new Date(date)
        positionViewAtIndex((selectedDate.getFullYear()) * 12 + selectedDate.getMonth(), ListView.Center) // index from month year
    }

    signal clicked(date date);  // onClicked: print('onClicked', date.toDateString())

 // private
    property date selectedDate: new Date()

    width: 500;  height: 100 // default size
    snapMode:    ListView.SnapOneItem
    orientation: Qt.Horizontal
    clip:        true

    model: 3000 * 12 // index == months since January of the year 0

    delegate: Item {
        property int year:      Math.floor(index / 12)
        property int month:     index % 12 // 0 January
        property int firstDay:  new Date(year, month, 1).getDay() // 0 Sunday to 6 Saturday

        width: root.width;  height: root.height

        Column {
            Item { // month year header
                width: root.width;  height: root.height - grid.height

                Text { // month year
                    anchors.centerIn: parent
                    text: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June',
                           'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'][month] + ' ' + year
                    font {pixelSize: 0.5 * grid.cellHeight}
                }
            }

            Grid { // 1 month calender
                id: grid

                width: root.width;  height: 0.875 * root.height
                property real cellWidth:  width  / columns;
                property real cellHeight: height / rows // width and height of each cell in the grid.

                columns: 7 // days
                rows:    7

                Repeater {
                    model: grid.columns * grid.rows // 49 cells per month

                    delegate: Rectangle { // index is 0 to 48
                        property int day:  index - 7 // 0 = top left below Sunday (-7 to 41)
                        property int date: day - firstDay + 1 // 1-31

                        width: grid.cellWidth;  height: grid.cellHeight
                        border.width: 0.3 * radius
                        border.color: new Date(year, month, date).toDateString() == selectedDate.toDateString()  &&  text.text  &&  day >= 0?
                                      'black': 'transparent' // selected
                        radius: 0.02 * root.height
                        opacity: !mouseArea.pressed? 1: 0.3  //  pressed state

                        Text {
                            id: text

                            anchors.centerIn: parent
                            font.pixelSize: 0.5 * parent.height
                            font.bold:      new Date(year, month, date).toDateString() == new Date().toDateString() // today
                            text: {
                                if(day < 0)                                               ['S', 'M', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'F', 'S'][index] // Su-Sa
                                else if(new Date(year, month, date).getMonth() == month)  date // 1-31
                                else                                                      ''
                            }
                        }

                        MouseArea {
                            id: mouseArea

                            anchors.fill: parent
                            enabled:    text.text  &&  day >= 0

                            onClicked: {
                                selectedDate = new Date(year, month, date)
                                root.clicked(selectedDate)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

     // Component.onCompleted: set(new Date()) // today (otherwise Jan 0000)
}
```

**Test.qml:**

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.15

Item{


    // Seçilen tarihi saklamak için bir property tanımlayın
    property var selectedDate: new Date()

    // Seçilen tarihi değiştiren bir fonksiyon oluşturun
    function selectDate(date) {
        selectedDate = date
    }

    ColumnLayout {
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        anchors.topMargin: 20

        // Üstteki tarih aralıklarını gösteren düğmeler
        RowLayout {
            spacing: 10
            Repeater {
                model: 7
                delegate: Button {
                    text: Qt.formatDateTime(new Date(selectedDate.getTime() + (index - 3) * 86400000), "dd MMM")
                    onClicked: selectDate(new Date(selectedDate.getTime() + (index - 3) * 86400000))
                }
            }
        }

        Button{
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            text: qsTr("Tarih Seç")
            onClicked: dateSelector.visible = true
        }

        DatePicker {
            width: 300
            height: 300
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            id: dateSelector
            visible: false
            Component.onCompleted: set(new Date()) // today
            onClicked: selectDate(date)
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that you "inject" the date as a property attached to the signal. You can do this differently like follows. You need to get the date out of the signal and store it in the existing variable "selectedDate". Than in the test.qml file where you use the component you can refer to that property. I fixed the code for you:

```
Item{
    id: root
    anchors.fill:parent

    // Seçilen tarihi saklamak için bir property tanımlayın
    property var selectedDate: new Date()

    // Seçilen tarihi değiştiren bir fonksiyon oluşturun
    function selectDate(date) {
        selectedDate = date
    }

    ColumnLayout {
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        anchors.topMargin: 20

        // Üstteki tarih aralıklarını gösteren düğmeler
        RowLayout {
            spacing: 10
            Repeater {
                model: 7
                delegate: Button {
                    text: Qt.formatDateTime(new Date(root.selectedDate.getTime() + (index - 3) * 86400000), "dd MMM")
                    onClicked: root.selectDate(new Date(root.selectedDate.getTime() + (index - 3) * 86400000))
                }
            }
        }

        Button{
            //anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            text: qsTr("Tarih Seç")
            onClicked: dateSelector.visible = true
        }

        DatePicker {
            id: dateSelector
            width: 300
            height: 300
            visible: true
            Component.onCompleted: set(new Date()) // today
            onClicked: {
                selectDate(selectedDate)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

2nd file:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

ListView {
    id: root

    function set(date) {
        selectedDate = new Date(date)
        positionViewAtIndex((selectedDate.getFullYear()) * 12 + selectedDate.getMonth(), ListView.Center) // index from month year
    }

    signal clicked();

    property date selectedDate: new Date()

    width: 500;  height: 100
    snapMode:    ListView.SnapOneItem
    orientation: Qt.Horizontal
    clip:        true

    model: 3000 * 12 

    delegate: Item {
        property int year:      Math.floor(index / 12)
        property int month:     index % 12 // 0 January
        property int firstDay:  new Date(year, month, 1).getDay() // 0 Sunday to 6 Saturday

        width: root.width;  height: root.height

        Column {
            Item { // month year header
                width: root.width;  height: root.height - grid.height

                Text { // month year
                    anchors.centerIn: parent
                    text: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June',
                           'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'][month] + ' ' + year
                    font {pixelSize: 0.5 * grid.cellHeight}
                }
            }

            Grid { // 1 month calender
                id: grid

                width: root.width;  height: 0.875 * root.height
                property real cellWidth:  width  / columns;
                property real cellHeight: height / rows // width and height of each cell in the grid.

                columns: 7 // days
                rows:    7

                Repeater {
                    model: grid.columns * grid.rows // 49 cells per month

                    delegate: Rectangle { // index is 0 to 48
                        property int day:  index - 7 // 0 = top left below Sunday (-7 to 41)
                        property int date: day - firstDay + 1 // 1-31

                        width: grid.cellWidth;  height: grid.cellHeight
                        border.width: 0.3 * radius
                        border.color: new Date(year, month, date).toDateString() == selectedDate.toDateString()  &&  text.text  &&  day >= 0?
                                      'black': 'transparent' // selected
                        radius: 0.02 * root.height
                        opacity: !mouseArea.pressed? 1: 0.3  //  pressed state

                        Text {
                            id: text

                            anchors.centerIn: parent
                            font.pixelSize: 0.5 * parent.height
                            font.bold:      new Date(year, month, date).toDateString() == new Date().toDateString() // today
                            text: {
                                if(day < 0)                                               ['S', 'M', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'F', 'S'][index] // Su-Sa
                                else if(new Date(year, month, date).getMonth() == month)  date // 1-31
                                else                                                      ''
                            }
                        }

                        MouseArea {
                            id: mouseArea

                            anchors.fill: parent
                            enabled:    text.text  &&  day >= 0

                            onClicked: {
                                root.selectedDate = new Date(year, month, date)
                                root.clicked()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

     // Component.onCompleted: set(new Date()) // today (otherwise Jan 0000)
}
```